# STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION with git svn

Tags: git, svn

I'm trying to migrate our code from an SVN repo (TortoiseSVN 1.9.3 64 bits) with about 1 GB data on it, to a TFS 2015 with a Git repo. I have Git on my computer (2.9.0.1) and when I try this command line:

```
git svn clone https://server/directory/trunk
```

It creates the .git folder, but then I have a perl.exe.stackdump file with the following problem

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=00000000000
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=00000006010B9448 rcx=00000006010B9448
rdx=00000006010C1788 rsi=0000000000000011 rdi=0000000000000000
r8 =0000000000000000 r9 =00000006010E8F68 r10=0000000100000000
r11=000000049F2423C9 r12=00000000FFFFC200 r13=00000000FFFFC208
r14=00000006010B0498 r15=00000006010B0408
rbp=00000000FFFFC218 rsp=00000000FFFFC1A8
program=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\perl.exe, pid 26220, thread main
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
End of stack trace
```

I have read that Git uses the .subversion/servers files to authenticate, so I guess this isn't the problem? I work exclusively on Windows.

Comment: What's your question? StackOverflow is not meant to filing bug reports, you could route the question to git dev community.

Comment: It's just that I don't know if it's a bug or just something I did wrong.

Comment: looks like a bug because of the exception `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`.

Comment: I have seen the same error, but in my case it was because of a broken network cable. I have 2 network adapters and because the network with SVN was "disconnected", Windows tried to route the traffic via the wrong network adapter.

Comment: I met because my svn server address is broken.

Comment: For me, the most effective way to resolve this and other issues during migrating a huge project from SVN to Git (on Windows), was to perform the actual `git svn clone ...` thing _not_ on Windows but on Linux. I've quickly set up an **Ubuntu** 20 VMware machine and the whole migration process ran successfully without _any_ errors (and I had plenty of them on Windows before).

Answer (score 7):

The cause is most likely due to the size of a large commit. I’ve seen similar issues before when fetching, cloning or rebasing while using Cygwin git when the change set is so large that Git and/or Perl run out of memory (it’s not fun when a colleague commits large video files).  Closing all other memory-intensive processes helps a lot. FWIW, I also found that I had less problems after upgrading Cygwin from 32-bit to 64-bit.

This seems to be a [well-known bug in Msys Git](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/274) and according to comments on the bug report, you should

> try calling successive `git svn fetch` calls to continue

Use of the 64-bit version of Git for Windows is also recommended. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue multiple times with older version on git

Try to upgrade to latest version (i am using 2.15 64 bit ) and it worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that SVN repo must be accessed via a http/https proxy.
for git-svn for windows, you must add proxy information in $home/.subversion/servers.(c:\Users\.subversion\servers), find global sector and uncommet http-proxy-host and http-proxy-port.
on windows, git-svn proxy settings is not same as git proxy settings, that's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - or, at least saw the same symptoms. What solved it for me was using **http** instead of **https**.

Using https, the error occurred before anything was even downloaded. Using http, it worked right away, downloading every file in the SVN repo.

The command I ran, following the recipe [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/perform-migration-from-svn-to-git?view=azure-devops):

```
git svn clone <SVN repo URL - with http> --prefix=svn/ --no-metadata --authors-file "authors-transform.txt" --stdlayout .
```

Answer (score 0):

Still append with the "lastest" git version (2.39) on MINGW64 (and visualsvn).

Like reowil and Tiger answers, my solution was to fix the http url path, using internal machine name and (the good) port vs the external mapping.

```
git svn clone --username=francois --trunk=/ http://myserver:8080/svn/mywebsite/trunk/ i:/temp/mywebsite`
```